Do operators change variance under unitary transformations?
Assume we have an unspecified source of quantum optical states and a measurement device that allows us to measure a certain property of states produced by this source. Providing we can take a large enough number of samples, we can examine those states and find out the property we measured has a certain variance $V^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_1-\bar{x})^2$. Now assume we insert some additional element, represented by a unitary transformation between the source and our measurement device.
Can we say something about the variance of the distribution of the quantity we measure?
For the sake of a concrete example, let's assume we have a laser source and a homodyne detector measuring q-quadrature, and we're inserting a beamsplitter such that we now measure one of the outputs of the beamsplitter. For a BS and Gaussian states, I have seen arguments with covariance matrices showing that the variance remains the same. But what if we do not know that the state is so nicely behaved, what if the state's structure is undetermined beforehand?
I assume to formalize the statement, we need to say something about the operator representing the quantity we're measuring - in our case this could be $\hat{q}$.
Can we argue that the beamsplitter does not change the variance of $\hat{q}$?
As in, are $V_{\rho}^2 := \langle \hat{q}^2 \rangle_{\rho} - \langle \hat{q}\rangle_{\rho}^2$ and $V_{U\rho U^{\dagger}}^2 := \langle \hat{q}^2 \rangle_{U\rho U^{\dagger}} - \langle \hat{q}\rangle_{U\rho U^{\dagger}}^2$ equal, where $U$ represents the BS trafo?
I appreciate any input!

I don't see why they should be. Write down the variances in the form of traces, and do the algebra yourself. Physically one would also expect it to be possible for this quantity to vary with time.

For the general case, I agree; I would have expected them to change. For the concrete example with a beamsplitter I did the math for Gaussian states and there it is true. So I suspect it might be true for general states. But for that, I fail to find a convincing argument.

Of course they can change. A unitary transformation can transform any pure state into any other pure state, and not all pure states have the same variances of some given observable. As a concrete example, if you send a squeezed vacuum state on a beam splitter you are mixing it with vacuum, and the result is that the variance of the squeezed quadrature is increased.
